# Intersection of 2 lines not really connected in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the code below I repeat one line (one with opacity=0 and other without it) in order to draw the intersection of 2 lines that are not connected. I am seeking a better way to achieve the same result. Using `arc` would also be a possible solution.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[fill=yellow] (0.25,0.5) rectangle (1.75,1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\draw [name path=a, opacity=0] (0,0) -- (2,2);% line that will be repeated
\draw [name path=b] (0,2) -- (2,0);
\path [name intersections={of=a and b,by=inter}];

\filldraw [yellow] (inter) circle (2pt);
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);% line repeated

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I only want to improve the way intersection between two lines is drawn, but keep the current aspect in the intersection of lines and rectangle. Moreover, the rectangle is not empty.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

OK, quick and dirty, so not sure how robust this is, but by using the `calc` library (section 13.5
"Coordinate Calculations" in the 2.10 PGF Manual) and tying things up using the `style args` key handle (section 55.4.4 "Defining Styles"), it at least goes part of the way to showing how it could be done.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    connect/.style args={(#1) to (#2) over (#3) by #4}{
        insert path={
            let \p1=($(#1)-(#3)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
            \n2={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, \n3={abs(#4)}, \n4={#4>0 ?180:-180}  in 
            (#1) -- ($(#1)!\n1-\n3!(#3)$) 
            arc (\n2:\n2+\n4:\n3) -- (#2)
        }
    },
}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[fill=yellow] (0.25,0.5) rectangle (1.75,1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw [name path=a] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\path [name path=b] (0,2) coordinate (x)  -- (2,0) coordinate (y);
\path [name intersections={of=a and b,by=inter}];

\draw [red, ultra thick, connect=(x) to (y) over (inter) by -6pt];
\draw [connect=(x) to (y) over (inter) by 3pt];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, we could go further and tie a *lot* of stuff up in the `connect` style.
This involves the use of `\pgfextra` (section 14.18 "The PGF-Extra Operation")
and the `pgfinterruptpath` environment (section 69.3.2 "Graphic Scope Environments").

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    connect/.style args={(#1) to (#2) over (#3) to (#4) by #5}{
        insert path={
            \pgfextra{
                \pgfinterruptpath
                    \path [name path=a] (#1) -- (#2);
                    \path [name path=b] (#3) -- (#4);
                    \path [name intersections={of=a and b,by=inter}];
                \endpgfinterruptpath                
            }
            let \p1=($(#1)-(inter)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
                            \n2={atan2(\y1,\x1)}, \n3={abs(#5)}, \n4={#5>0 ?180:-180}  in 
                            (#1) -- ($(#1)!\n1-\n3!(inter)$) 
                            arc (\n2:\n2+\n4:\n3) -- (#2)
        }
    },
}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[fill=yellow] (0.25,0.5) rectangle (1.75,1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw  (0,0) -- (2,2);

\draw [red, very thick, connect={(0,2) to (2,0) over (0,0) to (2,2) by -5pt}];
\draw [connect={(0,2) to (2,0) over (0,0) to (2,2) by 3pt}];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: This code no longer works with the newer version of TiKZ that comes with TeXLive 2014. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 13):

Here I keep the Jake's answer to my beginning question, which might be useful for someone. For this to work, the rectangle shall be "empty" and not in background layer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw [draw=white,double=black,double distance=\pgflinewidth,ultra thick] (0,2) -- (2,0);
\draw (0.25,0.5) rectangle (1.75,1.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Although an awesome [answer from Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111674/114143), I like things to be more smooth, so I implemented `controls` to his code (it ends up reducing a bit of the calculations as well):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

%%% Adapted from Mark Wibrow
\tikzset{%
    connect/.style args={(#1) to (#2) over (#3) by #4}{%
        insert path={%
            let \p1=($(#1)-(#3)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, \n2={abs(#4)}  in%
                (#1) --%
                ($(#1)!\n1-\n2!(#3)$) .. controls +(0:\n2/2) and +(180:\n2/2) ..%
                +(\n2,#4)%
                .. controls +(0:\n2/2) and +(180:\n2/2) .. ($(#1)!\n1+\n2!(#3)$) -- (#2)%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]
  \coordinate (a) at (-0.5,0.5);
  \coordinate (b) at (8,-0.5);
  \draw[ultra thick, name path=sine, domain=-1:8, smooth, samples=50] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
  \path[name path=line] (a) -- (b);
  \path[name intersections={of=sine and line}];
  \draw[blue, connect={(a) to ($(a)!.5!(intersection-2)$) over (intersection-1) by 12pt},
        connect={($(a)!.5!(intersection-2)$) to ($(intersection-2)!.5!(intersection-3)$) over (intersection-2) by -8pt},
        connect={($(intersection-2)!.5!(intersection-3)$) to (b) over (intersection-3) by 4pt}
        ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using the [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) package (development version at [`github`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3)).  This package introduces the ability to split a path where it intersects with another path (or itself), to insert gaps, and to splice in other paths (such as arcs).  So we do the following:

1. Save the two paths.
2. Split the *over* path where it crosses the *under* path.
3. Insert a decent sized gap at that point.
4. Splice in an arc into that gap.
5. Now split the *under* path where it crosses under this new version of the over path.
6. Insert a small gap at that point.

Since the gaps are genuine, there's no problem with the background path.  If there's a possibility that the arc might be upside down then the development version contains a version of the splicing code that ensures that the arc is always the right way up.

Here's the result:

[image: Like a bridge over a troubled crossing]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111660/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  intersections,
  backgrounds
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[fill=yellow] (0.25,0.5) rectangle (1.75,1.5);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\path [spath/save=a] (0,0) -- (2,2);% line that will be repeated
\path [spath/save=b] (0,2) -- (2,0);

\path[spath/save=arc] (0,0) arc[radius=1cm, start angle=180, delta angle=-180];

\tikzset{
  spath/split at intersections with={b}{a},
  spath/insert gaps after components={b}{8pt},
  spath/join components with={b}{arc},
  spath/split at intersections with={a}{b},
  spath/insert gaps after components={a}{4pt},
}

\draw[spath/use=a];
\draw[spath/use=b];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```