# Drawing little semicircle to show that two intersecting lines are not connected

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, intersections

I want my diagram to show that two intersecting lines are not actually connected, but one passes above the other.

The best result I would like to achieve would be a small semicircle as used in electrical circuits. Is this possible? There is something similar **[at TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-junctions/)** but it only handles horizontal and vertical lines.

I have this code that makes one of the lines stop a bit before the intersection by creating an empty node. This produces the expected result but I don't think it is the neatest way to do what I want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,1) {A};
\node (B) at (1,-1) {B};
\node (C) at (1,1) {C};
\node (D) at (-1,-1) {D};
\node (i) at (intersection of A--B and D--C) {}; 
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (D) -- (i);
\draw (i) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Pincopallino, could you post the contents of a small
compilable `.tex` file, starting with 
`\documentclass` and ending with 
`\end{document}`? Then I can paste it 
into my editor, reproduce your situation 
on my machine, and start thinking about 
a solution.

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-junctions/

Comment: Maybe also helpfuL: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115923/crossing-paths-in-tikz-without-intersection

Comment: @JohnWickerson here you are!

Comment: @Pincopallino I think this question would be a more useful and general reference for future visitors if the stuff about Feynman diagrams is removed. I would like to edit your question so that it reads simply: how can I draw two lines, with a little semicircle on one of them where they cross? Would that be ok with you?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes of course! I explicitly declared my intention to draw a Feynman diagram to help understanding which result I was expecting. Since you clearly understood the question and your answer is very clear there's no need for that anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Et voila.

- I define an `\intersect` command. If you call `\intersect{p1}{p2}{q1}{q2}`, it will draw the line `p1--p2` with a little semicircle where it intersects the line `q1--q2`.
- It draws the `p1--p2` line in three segments: a straight line from `p1` until `0.75mm` before the intersection point, and then a semicircle of diameter `1.5mm`, and finally the remainder of the straight line to `p2`.
- The code relies on TikZ's "distance modifiers", which are defined in Section 13.5.4 of the TikZ/PGF manual.

Does anybody know how to make the "loop" into a proper semicircle? I think that would look slightly better.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% \intersect{<p1>}{<p2>}{<q1>}{<q2>}
% draws the line p1--p2, showing a little semicircle
% where it intersects the line q1--q2.
\newcommand\intersect[4]{
  \draw let \p{c} = (intersection of #1--#2 and #3--#4) in
    (#1) -- ($(\p{c})!0.75mm!(#1)$) 
    to[bend right=90] ($(\p{c})!0.75mm!(#2)$) -- (#2)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,1) {A};
\node (B) at (1,-1) {B};
\node (C) at (1,1) {C};
\node (D) at (-1,-1) {D};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\intersect{C}{D}{A}{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is market as the best answer. However have a look to this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111660/intersection-of-2-lines-not-really-connected-in-tikz