# Want to Bend an Arrow Around an Arrow Instead of Intersecting

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the tikz package to make a chart. I want to have arrows that intersect but I don't want them to do so. What I want is for one arrow to bend around the other arrow so that the viewer doesn't get confused. I have attached an image of an example of an intersection where the arrow doesn't arc. Here, I want the diagonal arrow to arch around the vertical arrow. I am not sure if there is any way to do this, but I have been looking through StackExchange and haven't found anything yet.

Thank you for your help!!

[image: Not an ideal intersection]

Comment: Assume the original endpoints of the diagonal arrow are A and B. Calculate the intersecting point S, go a unit of your liking into each direction along the diagonal path creating the points H1 and H2. Then draw a path: straight from A to H1, circular arc from H1 to H2 with center in S, straight from H2 to B.

Comment: Should this be done via the intersections package?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want something like [Intersection of 2 lines not really connected in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111660)? Or do you rather want the lines to not touch at all? Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Could you add an image of your expected final output?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes! The bent arrow with the yellow rectangle (minus the yellow rectangle bit) is exactly what I was looking for! I can't believe I couldn't find that. Thank you! :)