# TIKZ - automatic bridge if two paths cross

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I am creating a diagram of dependencies for a system we are using, showing what can have an influence on what. That is working fine but I have a lot of intersections (and probably more to come) which can make it quite complicated read and follow the lines.

[image]

I'm now trying to draw bridges for those intersections, similar to [Intersection of 2 lines not really connected in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111660/intersection-of-2-lines-not-really-connected-in-tikz) , but automated as it would otherwise take too much time.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} [10pt,letterpaper]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{ele} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.427cm, minimum height=1.5cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=yellow!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.927cm]
    %Nodes
    \node (Person) [ele] {Person};
    \node (Club) [ele, right =of Person] {Club};
    \node (Member) [ele, below = of Person] {Member};
    \node (Bal) [ele, right = of Club] {Balance};
    \node (MP) [ele, below = of Bal] {Membership \\ Package};
    \node (Group) [ele, below = of Club] {Group};
    \node (Level) [ele, below = of MP] {Level};
    \node (Rec) [ele, below = of Group] {Recognition};
    \node (Pref) [ele, below = of Member] {Preference};
    %Lines
    \path (Person) edge [->,thick] (Member);
    \path (Member) edge [->,thick] (Group);
    \path (Pref) edge [->,thick] (Group);
    \path (Group) edge [<->,thick] (Rec);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick] (Level);
    \path (MP) edge [->,thick] (Level);
    \path (Group) edge [<->,thick] (Level);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick] (MP);
    \path (Group) edge [->,thick] (MP);
    \path (Group) edge [<->,thick] (Bal);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick] (Bal);
    \path (Bal) edge [->,thick] (Rec);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick] (Member);
    \path (MP) edge [->,thick,bend left=45] (Member);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick] (Group);
    \path (MP) edge [->,thick] (Bal);
    \path (Club) edge [->,thick,bend right=45] (Rec);
    \path (Level) edge [->,thick] (Rec);
    \path (Member) edge [->,thick,bend right=20] (Rec);
    \path (MP) edge [->,thick] (Person);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm also open to a radically other display of those dependencies if somebody has a better idea.

Comment: I personally would only rub the lines out with `[draw=white,double=black,double distance=\pgflinewidth]` since otherwise the plot will be super busy.

Comment: the current figure is not so good! my suggestion: rearrange nodes' position and use color for line connecting them.

Comment: what you mean with "automate"? as far as i can imagination, this is not simple even possible task. you should identified each intersection etc ... to ma taste, that you like to achieve will make your diagram less clear :-(.

Comment: @BlackMild Tried to rearrange the nods, didn't really help. Everytime I rearranged, the intersections simply moved. Also asked our graphics departement if they have a better idea to visualise this, but with no result.
Colours might be the way to go with marmot's proposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using the latest version of the [`spath3`](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) library (at time of writing this needs the development version but it will be uploaded to CTAN once it has undergone a bit more testing).

I've commented the code to explain what's going on, but the basic idea is as follows:

1. Define and save all the edges
2. Iterate through all pairs of edges to find the intersection points and insert a break in one of the edges at that point.
3. Widen those breaks and insert an arc in the gap, ensuring that the arc points "up" (this is the bit that needs the development version).
4. Now re-iterate through all pairs of edges and find the intersection points again (these will have moved since earlier due to the insertions of the arcs) and insert a break in the *other* path.
5. Widen those breaks a little bit.
6. Render all of the paths.

I modified the paths a little bit to ensure that there were no triple intersections (as they looked daft when the arcs were added).

Here's the result:

[image: Diagram with crossings rendered as bridges]

And here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl} [10pt,letterpaper]
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/414124/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  intersections,
  calc,
  shapes.geometric,
  arrows,positioning
}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% We're going to do a lot of iterating over the edges so we define a
% comma-separated list of them.
\def\Edges{%
Person/Member,%
Member/Group,%
Pref/Group,%
Group/Rec,%
Club/Level,%
MP/Level,%
Group/Level,%
Club/MP,%
Group/MP,%
Group/Bal,%
Club/Bal,%
Bal/Rec,%
Club/Member,%
MP/Member,%
Club/Group,%
MP/Bal,%
Club/Rec,%
Level/Rec,%
Member/Rec,%
MP/Person%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\tikzstyle{ele} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2.427cm, minimum height=1.5cm, align=center, draw=black, fill=yellow!50]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3.927cm]
    %Nodes
    \node (Person) [ele] {Person};
    \node (Club) [ele, right =of Person] {Club};
    \node (Member) [ele, below = of Person] {Member};
    \node (Bal) [ele, right = of Club] {Balance};
    \node (MP) [ele, below = of Bal] {Membership \\ Package};
    \node (Group) [ele, below = of Club] {Group};
    \node (Level) [ele, below = of MP] {Level};
    \node (Rec) [ele, below = of Group] {Recognition};
    \node (Pref) [ele, below = of Member] {Preference};

% Most of the edges will be lines, so we define them all as lines initially
% and then overwrite the ones that are curves.
% As we're defining them in a \foreach loop we have to work globally.
\foreach \source/\target in \Edges {
  \path[spath/save global=\source-\target] (\source) -- (\target);
}
% Now overwrite the ones that are meant to be curved
\path[spath/save global=MP-Member] (MP) to[bend left=45] (Member);
\path[spath/save global=Club-Rec] (Club) to[bend right=45] (Rec);
\path[spath/save global=Member-Rec] (Member) to[bend right=20] (Rec);
% It is best to avoid triple intersections so these two are also
% made into curves (they were straight in the original diagram)
\path[spath/save global=Group-Bal] (Group) to[bend left=20] (Bal);
\path[spath/save global=Bal-Rec] (Bal) to[bend left=5] (Rec);

% We now iterate through the list of edges and break each where it
% intersects with others.  For each pair we only want to break
% one of the edges, so when we consider an edge we only intersect
% it with edges that came earlier in the list.  To achieve this,
% after examining an edge we add it to the list \PreEdges that
% and we intersect each edge only with those in \PreEdges
\def\PreEdges{}
\foreach \sourceA/\targetA in \Edges
{
  \foreach \sourceB/\targetB in \PreEdges
  {
    % Split the first path where it meets the second path
    \tikzset{
      spath/split globally at intersections with={\sourceA-\targetA}{\sourceB-\targetB}
    };
  }
  % Now add the first path to the list of paths to intersect against
  % The \if is so that we don't get an empty entry at the start of
  % the list.
  % (This would be a bit simpler in LaTeX3)
  \if\PreEdges\relax\relax
  \xdef\PreEdges{%
    \sourceA/\targetA
  }
  \else
  \xdef\PreEdges{%
    \PreEdges,%
    \sourceA/\targetA
  }
  \fi
}

% At the intersection breaks we want to make a small gap and insert
% an arc.  This next line defines the arc (it will be scaled and
% transformed to fit in the gap so the actual size doesn't matter)
\path[spath/save=arc] (0,0) arc[radius=1cm, start angle=180, delta angle=-180];

% Now we iterate through the paths, adding gaps and then splicing in
% the arc.
\foreach \source/\target in \Edges
{
  \tikzset{
    spath/insert gaps globally after components={\source-\target}{8pt},
    spath/join components globally upright with={\source-\target}{arc},
  }
}

% This deals with the over paths, now we need to break the under paths
% where they intersect with the (new) over paths.  So we do our
% intersection double loop again, only with the paths in the opposite
% order in the splitting command.
\def\PreEdges{}
\foreach \sourceA/\targetA in \Edges
{
  \foreach \sourceB/\targetB in \PreEdges
  {
    \tikzset{
      spath/split globally at intersections with={\sourceB-\targetB}{\sourceA-\targetA}
    };
  }
  \if\PreEdges\relax\relax
  \xdef\PreEdges{%
    \sourceA/\targetA
  }
  \else
  \xdef\PreEdges{%
    \PreEdges,%
    \sourceA/\targetA
  }
  \fi
}

% Our last loop inserts gaps in the new breaks and renders each edge.
\foreach \source/\target in \Edges
{
  \tikzset{
    spath/insert gaps after components={\source-\target}{4pt},
  }
  \draw[spath/use=\source-\target,thick,->];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```