# Thickness of the text of nodes for crossing Bézier curves with bridge

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

Continuing https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581548, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,angles,calc}
%%% Stolen from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581548
\makeatletter
\tikzset{bridge/.code args={#1 over #2}{%
 \path[name path=tmp@bridge@path@B] #1;
 \tikzset{name intersections={of=#2 and tmp@bridge@path@B,
    by=tmp@i@0,total=\tmp@i@total}}
 \ifnum\tmp@i@total=0
  \typeout{These paths do not intersect. No bridge, sorry.}%
 \else
  \path[name path=tmp@bridge@path@C] (tmp@i@0) 
    circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}]; 
  \tikzset{name intersections={of=tmp@bridge@path@B and tmp@bridge@path@C,
    by={tmp@i@1,tmp@i@2},total=\tmp@i@total}}
  \ifnum\tmp@i@total=2
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (tmp@i@0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}]
     (current bounding box.south west) |-
     (current bounding box.north east) |- cycle;
    \draw[bridge-style] #1; 
   \end{scope}  
   \path let \p1=($(tmp@i@1)-(tmp@i@2)$),\n1={scalar(int(sign(\x1)))} in
    \ifnum\n1=-1
     pic [draw,line cap=round, angle radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius},
        bridge-arc] {angle=tmp@i@2--tmp@i@0--tmp@i@1}
    \else 
     pic [draw,line cap=round, angle radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius},
        bridge-arc] {angle=tmp@i@1--tmp@i@0--tmp@i@2}
    \fi; 
  \else
   \typeout{Given the bridge radius \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}, 
    the path is not suited to construct a nice bridge. No bridge, sorry.}%
  \fi   
 \fi 
},bridge radius/.initial=.5ex,
    bridge style/.code={\tikzset{bridge-style/.style={#1}}},
    bridge arc/.code={\tikzset{bridge-arc/.style={#1}}},
    bridge style={},bridge arc={}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[name path=A] (1,0) -- (1,1);
    \tikzset{bridge={(3,.5) to node[above,pos=.33333333333333333333333]{\(\mathit{c3}\colon b\)} (0,.5)} over A}
    \node at (2,.25) {\(\mathit{c3}\colon b\)};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Feeding it to `pdflatex` and opening the result in `evince` with 100% magnification gives us an image in which the text typeset with the bridge instructions is thicker/bolder than the same text typeset as usual:

[image: output]

In `qpdfview` at 100%, the difference is similar. At very high resolutions, such as 1000%, I failed to observe the difference in the thickness with either `evince` or `qpdfview`.  (There might be a tiny, hardly recognizable difference in the sharpness of the edges.)
Why is the difference in font weight so visible at low resolutions and how to make the weight of the text typeset with the bridge commands the same as usual?

Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34275 .

Comment: I can confirm this looking the same in Evince here. At higher zoom levels, the effect disappears.

Comment: Yes. Here too. Prints ok, though: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60649897#60649897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page stream of the PDF, the upper instance of the string appears twice at the same position, which leads to a bolder appearance in almost every PDF screen viewer. This is due to imprecision involved in rendering the Bezier curves of the font glyphs onto low resolution devices, in particular.

In order to fix it, the following can be done:

The first occurrence of the path is only used to calculate intersections. Insertion of the path into the page stream can be prevented by hiding this step in a phantom box, which still performs the calculation (but the result must be given global scope since `\phantom` puts a group around it.):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,angles,calc}
%%% Stolen from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581548
\makeatletter
\tikzset{bridge/.code args={#1 over #2}{%
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
 \phantom{%
   \path[name path=tmp@bridge@path@B] #1;
   \tikzset{name intersections={of=#2 and tmp@bridge@path@B,
      by=tmp@i@0,total=\tmp@i@total}}%
   \global\let\tmp@i@total\tmp@i@total%
 }
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
 \ifnum\tmp@i@total=0
  \typeout{These paths do not intersect. No bridge, sorry.}%
 \else
  \path[name path=tmp@bridge@path@C] (tmp@i@0) 
    circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}]; 
  \tikzset{name intersections={of=tmp@bridge@path@B and tmp@bridge@path@C,
    by={tmp@i@1,tmp@i@2},total=\tmp@i@total}}
  \ifnum\tmp@i@total=2
   \begin{scope}
    \clip (tmp@i@0) circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}]
     (current bounding box.south west) |-
     (current bounding box.north east) |- cycle;
    \draw[bridge-style] #1; 
   \end{scope}  
   \path let \p1=($(tmp@i@1)-(tmp@i@2)$),\n1={scalar(int(sign(\x1)))} in
    \ifnum\n1=-1
     pic [draw,line cap=round, angle radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius},
        bridge-arc] {angle=tmp@i@2--tmp@i@0--tmp@i@1}
    \else 
     pic [draw,line cap=round, angle radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius},
        bridge-arc] {angle=tmp@i@1--tmp@i@0--tmp@i@2}
    \fi; 
  \else
   \typeout{Given the bridge radius \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bridge radius}, 
    the path is not suited to construct a nice bridge. No bridge, sorry.}%
  \fi   
 \fi 
},bridge radius/.initial=.5ex,
    bridge style/.code={\tikzset{bridge-style/.style={#1}}},
    bridge arc/.code={\tikzset{bridge-arc/.style={#1}}},
    bridge style={},bridge arc={}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[name path=A] (1,0) -- (1,1);
    \tikzset{bridge={(3,.5) to node[above,pos=.33333333333333333333333]{\(\mathit{c3}\colon b\)} (0,.5)} over A}
    \node at (2,.25) {\(\mathit{c3}\colon b\)};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx; works like a charm! (Though diffpdf fails to see the difference, I see it.)