# How to make edges jump tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, node-connections

I am trying to pass arrows above the nodes on the image and join the "saturation" block. If you have an idea, I'm interested. Second thing, I wish I could put a second right angle on the arrow before reaching the west part of the sum. Any help will be welcome

[image]

Here's the code :

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
 
% More defined colors
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{comment}
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
 

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{pinstyle}=[pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 
 %% B

 
 %%sum
 \foreach \i in{1,2,3}{
 \node[draw,
    circle,
    minimum size=0.6cm] at (0.5*\i,-1*\i ) (sum\i) {};
 
\draw (sum\i.north east) -- (sum\i.south west)
    (sum\i.north west) -- (sum\i.south east);
 
\draw (sum\i.north east) -- (sum\i.south west)
(sum\i.north west) -- (sum\i.south east);
 
\node[above=-1pt] at (sum\i.center){\tiny $+$};
\node[left=-1pt] at (sum\i.center){\tiny $-$};
}
%%fast non linear

\node[draw,rectangle,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm,align=center,right=1.5 of sum2] (saturation) {Saturation \& \\ limiteur de taux};

\node[draw,rectangle,fill=green!60!black,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=3cm,align=center,right=1.5 of saturation] (fast) {Modèle \\ non linéaire \\ FAST};

\node[draw,rectangle, minimum size = 1.5cm, align=center, above left=of fast.north west  ] (cpb){Contrôle \\ CPB};

\node[draw,rectangle, minimum size = 1.5cm, align=center, below left=of fast.south west  ] (ipb){Contrôle \\ IPB};

%%Arrow
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=20pt]fast.east) -- ++  (1cm,0) |- (cpb.east)
    node[midway,above]{};
    
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=-20pt]fast.east) -- ++  (1cm,0) |- (ipb.east)
    node[midway,above]{};
    
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=10pt]ipb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|(sum3.west) node[midway,above]{};
   
\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=0pt]ipb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|  (sum2.west) node[midway,above]{};

\draw[-stealth] ([yshift=-10pt]ipb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|  (sum1.west) node[midway,above]{};

%%arrow cpb
\draw[-stealth] (cpb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|  (sum1.north) node[midway,above]{};

\draw[-stealth] (cpb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|  (sum2.north) node[midway,above]{};

\draw[-stealth] (cpb.west) -- ++  (-0.5cm,0) -|  (sum3.north) node[midway,above]{};

\end{tikzpicture} 
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I managed to connect the "sum" with a second right angle. However, I still have the problem of the connectors which must jump over the other connectors.

Comment: [This post, using `spath3` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583830/204164) should help you a lot.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549079/aligning-components-in-circuitikz-tikz/549100#549100

Comment: This question has already been asked here. [Marking intersection of two lines with a semicircle with no fill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/399847/138900) Do you agree with it?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is certainly the on-demand solution but it shows a devious use of arrows to address the problem.

This should be able to be improved by writing a command that automatically draws bridges.

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}


\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red,thick] (2,0)coordinate(A) -- ++(0,-3);
\draw[red,thick] (3,0)coordinate(B) -- ++(0,-3);
\draw[ultra thick,-{Arc Barb[harpoon,reversed]}] (0,-1) coordinate(C)-- (A|-C);
\draw[ultra thick,{Arc Barb[harpoon,reversed,right]}-{Arc Barb[harpoon,reversed]}] (A|-C) -- (B|-C);
\draw[ultra thick,{Arc Barb[harpoon,reversed,right]}-] (B|-C) -- ++(2,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]