# Tikz: crossing paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want a different layout for crossing lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{knots} %doesn't work?

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node (b) at (2,0) {b};
\node (c) at (1,1) {c};
\node (d) at (1,-1) {d};

\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (c) -- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is there a library to achieve a look like this:

[image: output]

Comment: Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111674/121799 ?

Comment: AFAIK there is no library for precisely that. You mention knots, which is a nice possibility, but it may not work with any possible path that you could think of (unless I am mistaken). On the other hand, what is wrong with  tex.stackexchange.com/a/111674/121799 ?